# sidenav overlay on top of sticky navbar, problem with the height of the sidenav overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, sidenav

I have this problem with the height of the sidenav overlay, I know that its messing with the javascript of the sticky navbar, but I have no idea how to make the height of the sidenav to be at its 100%. Any help would greatly appreciated!

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<html>     
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
 body {
   margin: 0;
   font-size: 28px;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 }


.header {
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
   padding: 30px;
   text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 9px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-animate-left" style="display:none;z-index:999;height:100%" id="mySidebar">
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large" onclick="w3_close()"> Close &times;</button>
  <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
<div class="w3-overlay w3-animate-opacity" onclick="w3_close()" style="cursor:pointer" id="myOverlay"></div>
<script>
function w3_open() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "block";
}

function w3_close() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
<div id="navbar">
<span class="w3-button w3-white w3-xlarge" onclick="w3_open()">&#9776;</span>

</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>

  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>

</div>

<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I just need the sidenav to displayed at its 100% height even if it is inside the sticky navbar. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set `position: relative` for your header.
2. Set `position: absolute; top: 0` for a sidebar.
   It works for me. I hope does for you too.