# fixed grid navbar and sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working now on a control panel using `HTML` `CSS`, I split the page using grid layout, but the problem is that the navbar & sidebar is not fixed
I have tried several methods including `position: fixed;`
overflow-y: auto but that didn't work for me.

https://jsfiddle.net/khalil_elyacubi/ckj8bqe9/2/

[picture one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFlFJ.png)

[picture two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9dh5.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sidenav overlay on top of sticky navbar, problem with the height of the sidenav overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53994351/sidenav-overlay-on-top-of-sticky-navbar-problem-with-the-height-of-the-sidenav)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are looking for something like this.

```js
$(".custom-select").each(function() {
    var classes = $(this).attr("class"),
      id = $(this).attr("id"),
      name = $(this).attr("name");
    var template = '<div class="' + classes + '">';
    template +=
      '<span class="custom-select-trigger">' +
      $(this).attr("placeholder") +
      "</span>";
    template += '<div class="custom-options">';
    $(this)
      .find("option")
      .each(function() {
        template +=
          '<span class="custom-option ' +
          $(this).attr("class") +
          '" data-value="' +
          $(this).attr("value") +
          '">' +
          $(this).html() +
          "</span>";
      });
    template += "</div></div>";
  
    $(this).wrap('<div class="custom-select-wrapper"></div>');
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).after(template);
  });
  $(".custom-option:first-of-type").hover(
    function() {
      $(this)
        .parents(".custom-options")
        .addClass("option-hover");
    },
    function() {
      $(this)
        .parents(".custom-options")
        .removeClass("option-hover");
    }
  );
  $(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function() {
    $("html").one("click", function() {
      $(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
    });
    $(this)
      .parents(".custom-select")
      .toggleClass("opened");
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(".custom-option").on("click", function() {
    $(this)
      .parents(".custom-select-wrapper")
      .find("select")
      .val($(this).data("value"));
    $(this)
      .parents(".custom-options")
      .find(".custom-option")
      .removeClass("selection");
    $(this).addClass("selection");
    $(this)
      .parents(".custom-select")
      .removeClass("opened");
    $(this)
      .parents(".custom-select")
      .find(".custom-select-trigger")
      .text($(this).text());
  });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
html,body{
  height:100%;
}

.container{ 
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 260px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "sidebar header"
    "sidebar main";
    height: 100%;
}
/*------------------------------------*/
             /* Navbar */
/*------------------------------------*/
.navbar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    position: sticky;

}
.left-nav a{
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.left-nav a:hover{
    color: rgb(187, 187, 187);
}
.left-nav i:hover{
    color: rgb(187, 187, 187);
}   


.navbar{
    grid-area: header;
    background-color: rgba(38, 40, 48, 1);
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}
/*------------------------------------*/
            /* Sidebar */
/*------------------------------------*/
.sidebar{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.sidebar{
    grid-area: sidebar;
    background-color: rgba(38, 40, 48, 1);
    color: white;
}
.logo{

    padding: 20px;

}
.logo img{
    width: 100%;
}

.category-head{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 83%;
    justify-content: space-between;

    font-size: small;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.452);
    margin-top: 15%;
    
}
.width_element{
    width: 81%;
}

.category-pages, .category-select{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 84%;
    

}
.category-select{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
 

    padding: 2.5% 7%;
    color: #C6C6C7;
    font-weight: 400;
    transition: .3s;
    font-size: 0.93rem;
}
.category-select:hover{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;

}


.categorySelected{
    color: rgba(255, 185, 97, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px -13px #ff9d1c6b;
    background-color: rgba(53, 56, 65, 1);
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding: 3.5% 7%;
}

/*-------select box-------*/

  select {
    z-index: 3;
    float: left;
  }
  
  /** Custom Select **/
  .custom-select-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .custom-select-wrapper select {
    display: none;
  }
  .custom-select {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 13px/1.5 "Poppins", sans-serif;
  }
  .custom-select-trigger {
    position: relative;
    /* display: block; */
    min-width: 130px;
    padding: 6% 104px 6% 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #6e7c83;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(53, 56, 65, 1);
    border-radius: 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  
  }
  .custom-select-trigger:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px 0px rgba(70, 73, 83, 0.10);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px 0px rgb(70, 73, 83,0.10);
  }
  .custom-select-trigger:before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 1px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 3px;
    right: 50px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
  }
  .custom-select-trigger:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c7d1d6;
    border-right: 1px solid #c7d1d6;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-50%);
    transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
  }
  .custom-select.opened .custom-select-trigger:after {
    margin-top: 3px;
    transform: rotate(-135deg) translateY(-50%);
  }
  .custom-options {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
  
    margin: 10px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1); */
  
    background: rgba(53, 56, 65, 1);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(-15px);
    border: 0;
    
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;

  }
  .custom-select.opened .custom-options {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: all;
    transform: translateY(-8px);
  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px 0px rgb(70, 73, 83,0.10);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px 0px rgb(70, 73, 83,0.10);
  }
  .option-hover:before {
    background: #f9f9f9;
  }
  .custom-option {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 22px;
    font: 13px/1.5 "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #b5b5b5;
    line-height: 47px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.05s ease-in-out;
  }
  .custom-option:first-of-type {
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  }
  .custom-option:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  }
  .custom-option:hover,
  .custom-option.selection {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(253, 183, 102, 0.1);
    border: 1px solid rgba(253, 183, 102, 1);
  }

  /*-------select box end*-------/




/*------------------------------------*/
          /* main content */
/*------------------------------------*/
.main{ 
    justify-content: start;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: main;
    background-color: rgba(30, 31, 37, 1);
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.cotainer{
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;
}


.server-banner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    /* background: url(./baner1.png) no-repeat; */
    filter: blur(5px);
    border-radius: 10px;
    /* background-size: cover; */
    overflow: hidden;

}
.server-banner img{
    width: 100%;
    
    position: relative;
    top: -140px;
    opacity: 25%; 
    z-index: -1;
}


.server{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 3%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 55px;
}


.server img{
    width: 9%;
}

.server-members{
    padding-left:2%;
}
/*------------------------------------*/
          /* Scroll Bar */
/*------------------------------------*/

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
  }
  
  /* Track */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent; 
  }
   
  /* Handle */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888; 
  }
  
  /* Handle on hover */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555; 
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/solid.min.css">

    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-rOA1PnstxnOBLzCLMcre8ybwbTmemjzdNlILg8O7z1lUkLXozs4DHonlDtnE7fpc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>grid dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="left-nav">
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>   Support server</a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-code"></i>   Commands</a>
            </div>
            <div class="right-nav">user.icos</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="logo"><img src="./logo.png" alt="" srcset=""></div>


  
                <select name="potencial" id="potencial" class="custom-select sources" placeholder="Ticket Manager">
                  <option value="DH" selected><img src="server-logo.png" alt="server-logo"> Ticket Manager</option>
                  <option value="A">Ticket Manager</option>
                  <option value="B">Ticket Manager</option>
                  <option value="C">Ticket Manager</option>
                  <option value="D">Ticket Manager</option>
                  <option value="D">Ticket Manager</option>
                  <option value="D">Ticket Manager</option>
                  <option value="D">Ticket Manager</option>
                  <option value="D">Ticket Manager</option>
                  <option value="D">Ticket Manager</option>
                  <option value="D"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i>Ticket Manager</option>
                </select>
            
                <div class="category-head">General  <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                <div class="category-pages">
                    <div class="category-select categorySelected"><div class="title">Overview</div> <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i></div></div>
                    <div class="category-select "><div class="title">Premium</div> <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-crown"></i></div></div>
                </div>

                <div class="category-head width_element">Customise bot<i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                <div class="category-pages">
                    <div class="category-select"><div class="title">Settings</div> <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></div></div>
                    <div class="category-select"><div class="title">Pannels</div> <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></div></div>
                    <div class="category-select"><div class="title">Logs</div> <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-history"></i></div></div>
                    <div class="category-select "><div class="title">Archived tickets</div> <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-folder-open"></i></div></div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="cotainer">
                <p>content</p> 
                  <div class="server-info">

                    <div class="server-banner"> <img src="./baner1.png" alt=""></div>


                    <div class="server">
                        <img src="./server-logo-lg.png" alt="">


                        <div class="server-members">
                            <div class="server-name">Ticket Manager</div>
                            <div class="server-id">ID: 123456789</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                  </div>


                  <h1>some text here</h1>
                  <h1>some text here</h1>
                  <h1>some text here</h1>
                  <h1>some text here</h1>
                  <h1>some text here</h1>
                  <h1>some text here</h1>
                  <h1>some text here</h1>
                  <h1>some text here</h1>
                  <h1>some text here</h1>
                  <h1>some text here</h1>
                  <h1>some text here</h1>
                  <h1>some text here</h1>

            </div>
            

        </div>
        
    </div>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```